# Animating / Move canvas image that has been placed by putImageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, putimagedata

I have a jpeg image that has been decoded, and I am writing it to canvas with putImageData. Is it possible to then move this image around? I cannot find any documentation on it.

The idea is that I will crop a certain part of the decoded image with dirtyX and dirtyY, and now I would like to crop another part of the image. I'm using the decoded image like a spritesheet.

Comment: Yes you can animate it but there's not included method like context.animate(). You'll have to use requestAnimationFrame ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame ) and then move the image each frame.

Comment: So I will have to call putImageData on every call I use with requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: I think the best thing would be to getImageData() to get information of all the pixels, then modify the ones you need to move and then putImageData() http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a version of this but the performance is very low. It seems that putImageData takes about 40ms to process the image data on every call (so frames are skipped).

Comment: putimagedata is what is usually used for realtime video effects so it should be fast enough. Give treeno's answer a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the clipping version of `drawImage` to draw your individual sprites to the canvas**

*(Don't use getImageData & putImageData for clipping since drawImage is easier and faster.)*

If you want to use your decoded image as a spritesheet then you can use the canvas's clipping version of `context.drawImage` to clip a particular sub-section of your spritesheet and draw it to the canvas.

Here's a previous SO post about the clipping version of `drawImage`.

[HTML / Java Script Canvas - how to draw an image between source and destination points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080776/html-java-script-canvas-how-to-draw-an-image-between-source-and-destination)

Here's example code and a Demo:

Note that the way to "move" sprites on the canvas is to clear the canvas and redraw the desired sprite in it's new position. (You can't "move" an existing drawing on the canvas).

```js
$(window).load(function(){

  // canvas related variables       
  var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

  // animation related variables
  var lastFlap,lastMove;

  // define a bird object
  // x,y are the position of the bird on the canvas
  // spriteX,spriteY is the position of the first desired
  //      sprite image on the spritesheet
  // width,height is the size of 1 sprite image
  // currentFrame is the index of which of the sprite images to display
  // currentDirection.  The sprite plays forward and then backward to
  //      accomplish 1 flap.  This determines if the next frame index will
  //      be increased (play forward) or decreased (play backward)
  var bird={
    x:30,
    y:30,
    spriteX:0,
    spriteY:52,
    width:51,
    height:51,
    frames:4,
    currentFrame:0,
    currentDirection:1
  }

  // load the spritesheet and start the animation
  var spritesheet=new Image();
  spritesheet.onload=start;
  spritesheet.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/birdSpritesheet.png";
  function start(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  function animate(time){

    // request another animation frame

    if(bird.x<canvas.width){
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    // if the lastFlap or lastMove times don't aren't set, then set them

    if(!lastFlap){lastFlap=time;}
    if(!lastMove){lastMove=time;}

    // calculate the elapsed times since the last flap and the last move

    var elapsedFlap=time-lastFlap;
    var elapsedMove=time-lastMove;

    // if 50ms have elapsed, advance to the next image in this sprite

    if(elapsedFlap>50){

      // advance to next sprite on the spritesheet (flap)

      bird.currentFrame+=bird.currentDirection;

      // clamp bird.currentFrame between 0-3  (0,1,2,3)
      // (because there are 4 images that make up the whole bird sprite)

      if(bird.currentFrame<0 || bird.currentFrame>bird.frames-1){
        bird.currentDirection*=-1;
        bird.currentFrame+=bird.currentDirection;
      }

      // reset the flap timer

      lastFlap=time;
    }

    // locate the current sprite from the spritesheet

    var sx=bird.spriteX+bird.currentFrame*bird.width;
    var sy=bird.spriteY;

    // if 100ms have elapsed, move the bird across the canvas

    if(elapsedMove>100){
      bird.x+=3;
      lastMove=time;
    }

    // clear the whole canvas

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    // draw the current part of the bird sprite at the current bird.x

    ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
                  sx,sy,bird.width,bird.height,
                  bird.x,bird.y,bird.width,bird.height
                 );

  }

}); // end $(function(){});
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>The canvas animating a clipped sprite</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
<br>
<h4>The spritesheet</h4>
<img id=spritesheet src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/birdSpritesheet.png'>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I will put this into practise after the weekend let you know how I get on. Best,

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No :-)
Since canvas draws in immediate-mode it doesn't know that you have drawn an image on the canvas. So, you cannot draw it on the canvas one single time and move the painted image around. You will have to manually redraw the complete image in each animationframe at a new postion. 
You can do that using the `requestAnimationFrame()` as Jonas Grumann explains.